# alternative peak and valley algorithm confusion

Tags: algorithm

Wondering if anyone have worked on similar problem before? And my question is, why {8, 6} are peaks? I think 8 is peak, but since 6 is smaller than 8, it should not be a peak? Thanks.

In an array of integers, a "peak" is an element which is greater than or equal to the adjacent integers and a "valley" us an element which is less than or equal to the adjacent integers. For example, in the array {5,8,6,2,3,4,6} {8,6} are peaks and {5,2} are valleys. Given an array of integers, sort the array into an alternating sequence of peaks and valleys.

Example,

Input: {5,3,1,2,3}
Output: {5,1,3,2,3}

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Sort the array normally, then swap every even-numbered elements with the next one.

Comment: similar? [Explain the Peak and Flag Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457870/explain-the-peak-and-flag-algorithm?rq=1)

Comment: @n.m., thanks but why in the output of the sample, {5,1,3,2,3} has an alternative peak and valley? I think 5 is always peak in the input and outptu array -- nothing changed? Thanks.

Comment: @RyanVincent, but why in the output of the sample, {5,1,3,2,3} has an alternative peak and valley? I think 5 is always peak in the input and outptu array -- nothing changed? :)

Comment: Not alternative. Alternate. A different word.

Comment: @n.m., thanks for the correction. But why {5,1,3,2,3} has alternate peak and valley comparing to {5,3,1,2,3}? I think 1 is always valley, no change. :)

Comment: Alternate doesn't mean different from. You don't compare two different arrays. It means going on and off repeatedly, as in alternate current.

Comment: @n.m., thanks but still confused. Could you elaborate a bit more why {5,1,3,2,3} is alternating sequence of peaks and valleys of  {5,3,1,2,3}?

Comment: @n.m., did more investigation, I think you mean for array {5,1,3,2,3}, 5 is peak, then 1 is valley, then 3 is peak, then 2 is valley and then 3 is peak, and it is how we call it alternating correct? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the solution in the book assumes that all elements are unique, but problem statement contains nothing about it. Moreover it contains examples with duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `6` referred to is the 2nd `6` at the end of the sequence.  This fits the description well (if not made very clear) and is backed up by `5` being a valley.

An alternating sequence of peaks and valleys is a sequence such that either all of the elements in odd-numbered positions are peaks and those in even-numbered positions are valleys, or vice-versa.  The output sequence in the example demonstrates the elements of the input sequence sorted in such a way.

Comment: Thanks David, but why in the output of the sample, {5,1,3,2,3} has an alternative peak and valley? I think 5 is always peak in the input and outptu array -- nothing changed? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you figured it out. :)  Edited answer to a be a bit more complete nonetheless.